# PDF cache(under temporary internet files\content.ie5) issue for IE6 and IE8

Tags: java, internet-explorer, caching, pdf, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC Controller which is request mapped to an URL. On hitting this URL a save/open PDF pop-up occurs.On Opening it,the PDF is saved under temporary internet files/content.ie5 as cache. However, this PDF shouldn't be saved as cache due to security reasons. Later I found a solution opening the PDF inline using:

```
pResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "inline;filename=csi.pdf");
```

The PDF doesnt save as cache for IE8.However for IE6 it is cached again. To Handle this I have using this:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

Now,This solution works for IE6 and doesnt work for IE8. Can someone please let me know how this can be handled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should rely on caching/not caching if you are dealing with secure content, since it's very browser/application specific. For instance, have you tried on Firefox? What if the users like some different (and unusual) browsers?

You should serve it over `https`, which will disable all possible caching on the network due to the encryption, but I believe it might still be cached by Acrobat when opened.

Another option is to make it a password-protected pdf.

Comment: Not really https is already used. And Password protected  doesnt cover all the requirements. This has to be the solution as it works for one browser at a time.

Comment: @Goutham, what I'm saying is you can't rely on caching behavior - it might not cache on your machine, but may cache in mine because I use a different browser, and may be cached on Windows' recent files, or on Acrobat Reader's recent files, etc. You can't possibly bypass all of those, so if you want your file to be secure, encrypt it instead of worrying about stuff you have no control whatsoever.

Comment: The only security reason is as anyone with Admin rights can access cache of all the users.So cache shouldnt be saved.

Comment: Also , only 2 browsers are used by all the users. IE6 and IE8.